# An example of a non trivial open cover of an arbitary metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I think the trivial example of the open cover of the set is itself.I dont know any example .

Comment: How about just covering it with open balls?

Comment: In general, there might not be any other open covers at all, e.g. if the metric space has ≤1 point.

Comment: What do you mean by non-trivial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be the metric space. Fix some point $x$ in $X$ and consider the collection of balls of radius $r>0$ about $x$. This may coincide with a trivial cover.

Answer (score 2):

If your space has at least two points, take two points and let $r>0$ be smaller than the distance between them. Then the collection of all open balls, centered on all points of the space, with radius $r$ is a non-trivial cover.